# How to assign $(this) with multiple same class vs unique id

Tags: jquery, class, this

I have asked a similar question in the past but I put together the following example that better illustrates the results i'm seeking.

Using unique id with classic js.(it works)

```
<style>
#par {width:350px; background:#DDD; padding:5px;}
#tatx {color:#C00;}
</style>

<div id="par">
Select an option, then, select another option<br>
<select id="sl" onChange="sltota();tatotx()">
<option value="item 1">option 1</option>
<option value="item 2">option 2</option>
<option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
    <p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea id="ta" onChange="tatotx()"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div id="tatx">div text</div>
</div>

<script>
function sltota() {
slVal = document.getElementById('sl').value;
taVal = document.getElementById('ta').value;
document.getElementById('ta').value = taVal + ('- ') + slVal + ('\n');
}

function tatotx() {
taVal = document.getElementById('ta').value;
document.getElementById('tatx').innerHTML = taVal;
}
</script>
```

Now I'm trying to modify this code using Jquery $(this) with multiple elements with the same class. but I can not make it work any help is appreciated.(this does not work)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
li {margin-bottom:7px; background:#DDD; padding:5px;}
#par {width:350px;}
.tatx {color:#C00;}
</style>

<div id="par">
<ul>

<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
<option value="item 1">option 1</option>
<option value="item 2">option 2</option>
<option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>
<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
<option value="item 1">option 1</option>
<option value="item 2">option 2</option>
<option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>
<li>
Select an option, then, select another option.<br>
<select class="sl">
<option value="item 1">option 1</option>
<option value="item 2">option 2</option>
<option value="item 3">option 3</option>
</select><br>
<p>Selected options values are passed to textarea<br>
<textarea class="ta"></textarea>
<p>Textarea value is passed to div as text
<div class="tatx">Div Text</div>
</li>

</ul>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li > .sl').on('change', function() {
    $(this).sibling('.ta').val($(this).val());
    $(this).sibling('.tatx').val($('.ta').val());

});
}
</script>
```

Comment: well, 1: the variables names are a little on the confusing side,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. It is `siblings`, not `sibling`. And `siblings` only looks at immediate siblings, not their descendents. `.tatx` is fine because its a direct sibling, but `.ta` is a child of a sibling (of a `p` element) so you must traverse the found siblings using `find()`
2. Your JS code is missing a `);` at the end to close the `ready` statement
3. Divs cannot have their content set using `val(),` you need to set `html()`

So...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li > .sl').on('change', function() {
    $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val($(this).val());
    $(this).siblings('.tatx').html($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: . should I write another function for to update .tatx class?  I notice this does not update.

Comment: no, i had a typo in my answer! I fixed it, try again with the updated code for `.tatx` (needs to be `siblings('.tatx')`, not `siblings().('.tatx')` )

Comment: Works like a charm.
$(document).ready(function(){
$('li > .sl').on('change', function() {
    $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val($(this).val());
    $(this).siblings('.tatx').html($(this).val());
    });
});

Comment: Interesting that '.ta' requires .find where '.tatx' does not. I think you answered this question with your initial comment. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ok, so close, I have tried to .append ".ta" so I retain current options within the textarea and add to them like I have done in the js example I provided but I have not figured out yet. Any thoughts?

Comment: figured it out. var taVal = $('.ta').val();
    $(this).siblings().find('.ta').val(taVal + $(this).val());

Comment: for appending, that looks solid to me

Answer (score 0):

It should be `siblings` not sibling:

```
$('li > .sl').on('change', function() {
    $(this).siblings('.ta').val($(this).val());
    $(this).siblings('.tatx').val($('.ta').val());   
});
```

There's no sibling selector but [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) in jQuery.